# Python Class Layout - Conventions

Tags: python, object-oriented

What is the proper or standard way to layout a class. If a class where to have attributes, methods, private attributes, private methods, class property (methods), and class methods. I am done 99% of my coding procedurely and beyond working with ORM haven't focused to much on OOP. I am changing that in a current project and was just curios what the standard way of organizing your classes was.

```
Class MyClass():
   attr1 = value1
   attr2 = value2
   _attr3 = value3
   def __init__(self):
      do some stuff
   def do_something(self):
      do some more stuff

   def __do_something_else(self):
      more stuff
   @property()
   def attr4(self):
       return do_some_stuff_else()

   @classmethod()
   def generator_a_bunch_of_these(cls):
       do_some_more_things
```

Comment: Have a look at [PEP8 - The Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Note that double leading underscores are generally a bad idea. You can't even use them in subclasses, must less from somewhere else (yes, that's *sometimes* justified), because the name is mangled.

Comment: Your use of class-level attributes (`attr1`, `attr2` and `_attr3`) is often a very bad idea.  Folks who come from languages with static declarations are sometimes confused by this and think that these class-level attributes somehow important.  Also, 80% of the time, you want `@staticmethod` not `@classmethod`.

Comment: @Omnius: What parts of the built-in library have you read?  What other open-source libraries do you use normally?  Have you read that code to see how it's formatted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for such answers in here: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/

Basics is in the most famous one: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

By the looks and code i have seen, you got pretty good idea about that. Good luck,  hope it'll help :)

**UPDATE:** While following pep rules you come up with about the same anyway :) so pure convention for classes - yes there is none or i haven't heard of it. How you should write it - pep8. By common programming sense you write you variables, fields above methods. Same things happen with everything else. Just code as the Holy Zen of Python teaches you:

> - Beautiful is better than ugly.
> - Explicit is better than implicit.
> - Simple is better than complex.
> - Complex is better than complicated.
> - Flat is better than nested.
> - Sparse is better than dense.
> - Readability counts.
> - Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
> - Although practicality beats purity.
> - Errors should never pass silently. Unless explicitly silenced.
> - In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
> - There should be one - and preferably only one - obvious way to do it.
> - Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
> - Now is better than never.
> - Although never is often better than *right* now.
> - If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
> - If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
> - Namespaces are one honking great idea - let's do more of those!

Comment: I have read through these documents prior to my question and did find a wealth of good information however none that addressed the question of how the class should be physically laid out. Perhaps a convention doesn't exist and I just need to make some rules for our office on how we want to do it.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, o thought to reply a comment but then i realized that its more of an update and clarification.